# Add a new Setup Message ID to Inno Setup Messages - Language Files (.isl)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to add a new Setup Message ID named `SetupMessageID[msgButtonNotify]` to Inno Setup.

And I also need its text to be modifiable using .isl Files like `msgButtonNotify=Notify`.

How can I add a new Setup Message ID without getting any Exception Message?

If it is possible, where should I add it in its Source Code including `MsgIDs.pas`?

How can I update `MessageHdrID` in `Struct.pas` to add a new Setup Message ID?

*Because, Jordan Russel gives this warning on `MsgIDs.pas`: `{ Note: When any messages are added/deleted/changed, MessagesHdrID needs to be updated in Struct.pas }`*

I can't understand what should I update in `Struct.pas`.

*The lines whose related to this warning can bee seen in `Struct.pas` are:*

`TMessagesHdrID = array[0..63] of AnsiChar;` and

`MessagesHdrID: TMessagesHdrID = 'Inno Setup Messages (5.5.3)'{$IFDEF UNICODE}+' (u)'{$ENDIF};`

What should be updated in those lines?

What Jordan Russel means `Update` there???

Should I increase the value of the AnsiChar Array or anything else?

I ask this because when I adding new Setup Message ID called `msgButtonNotify` to `MsgIDs.pas` and increasing `TMessagesHdrID`'s AnsiChar Array Length to 65,
adding my new Setup Message ID in `Default.isl`, then compiling project and try a testing Compile with Inno Setup Compiler, Setup Loader says `Message name "ButtonNotify" in Default.isl is not recognized by this version of Inno Setup`.

Why this Exception is occurring?

Are there any other Unit I have to update when adding a new Setup Message ID in Inno Setup Compiler's Source Code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why don't you use `[CustomMessages]`?

Comment: Because, Custom Messages haven't a Message called `{cm:ButtonNotify}`.  Using `[CustomMessages]` is it possible to add a new Custom Message?

Comment: And Jordan Russel says adding new Message IDs is possible in the line I shown.

Comment: And also I added a button in Inno Setup Wizard called `Notify: TNewButton`.........This new Message ID should be added for its Caption............

Comment: How did you add the button? Did you modify Inno Setup source code? Or did you use the Pascal script - `Code` section?

Comment: Yes, I added it via Inno Setup Source Code.........No I don't used Pascal Script Code Section and internally added it in `WizardForm`.

Comment: Why do you recompile Inno Setup to add a button? Well, I do not think you can expect anyone here to help you with such hacking.

Comment: I didn't hacked.............Just added........And I'm not violated its licence and not removed the `About Setup...Box`.. :) Thank you for the answer...........It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a point of recompiling Inno Setup to add a new message.

---

Use the [`CustomMessages` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) in the `.isl` or the `.iss` to add new messages.

```
[CustomMessages]
ButtonNotify=&Notify
```

And then use the [`CustomMessage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_custommessage) (or the [`{cm:...}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cm)) to load the message.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  NotifyButton: TNewButton;
begin
  NotifyButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  NotifyButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  NotifyButton.Caption := CustomMessage('ButtonNotify');
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Shit..........Even knowing to add tons of codes to scripts, I didn't know even how to use built in `[CustomMessages]` function...........What kind of a man am I...... :(